# Remove Bootstrap Collapse' inline height property set by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When using the Bootstrap collapse plugin, I notice in the Elements panel that there is an inline height property of the element animated. I would like to **remove** this (from the actual **core** Collapse.js / Transition.js plugin) as I'm using pure CSS3 animations/transitions.
[image: inline height]

the reason is two fold : a/ I don't need it, b/ it's conflicting with my own animation, the element firstly expands to the height calculated by the script, and then after a 15ms pause folds down to height: 100% (as I wish)

I emphasize: *I don't want to override it, I want to **remove** it completely* (please no answers with overriding)

Answer (score 0):

Height is being set by anything that looks like:

```
this.$element[dimension](0)...
```

You'll need to hunt those down in both `.hide` and `.show` plugin methods.

Comment: Id' appreciate a pointer as to which file etc? is there a generic switch that disables that behavior?